# Tool to manage string literals used for parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json

We parse a lot of JSON in our app - without the back-end, it would be a pretty useless app. I know this goes for a bunch of other apps out there as well.  In order to parse JSON, we need a list of keys to get to the data.  I'd like to know what is considered 'best practice' or at least 'damn good practice' for managing these paths/string literals. Is there a tool out there that helps manage such keys and reduces duplication?

1. Hard-coding them is definitely not an option although to be frank, if our back-end programmers change the key, in concept, a simple find/replace in XCode (or whatever IDE you're using) would suffice. It's ugly and unclean and I just feel dirty putting string literals all over my code though.
2. What I'm currently doing now is putting them all into my PCH file, which means I end up with:

   `#define kBookmarksSearchResultsIDFieldName                @"business.id"`

   `#define kBookmarksSearchResultsNameFieldName              @"business.name"`

   `#define kBookmarksSearchResultsThumbnailURLFieldName @"business.display_image.images.small_mobile.source"`

   `#define kBookmarksBusinessCategoryArrayFieldName          @"business.categories"`

   This gets unwieldy real fast though since now I have around a thousand lines of these things in my PCH file.
3. The other option I'm considering is breaking these up into separate .h files - but then if two components of my app end up using the same key (for example, a `business` object is embedded into the JSON for a bookmark, or for a review of that business) then I have to import the .h that contains the JSON paths for the `business` object. So in this case I'm still importing all of the same data, it's just the file organization that's cleaner.

My objectives are:

1. Easy management of string literals used for parsing JSON
2. Reduce the amount of duplication needed
3. Easy changing/replacement of JSON paths if/when needed

Is option 3 that I listed above (separate .h files) my best option? What do you guys use, and am I missing an easy tool out there (and no, JSONModel isn't an option because of the way it requires your JSON keys to match your ivar/property names - our back-end supports a number of platforms so we can't change the JSON keys just for iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using a library such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org) which allows you to map a JSON document to a set of Objective-C classes.  This means you can read the document in and get an array of objects you can manipulate by properties instead of having to keep track of key names.  It's much easier, and Xcode will autocomplete your property names as you work with the classes.

It takes some setup, but you only have to do it once. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this answer - there's a very cool library called [Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) - not perfect, there are some issues with typecasting but still a very solid effort.